# User not in sudoers ... but it is!

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am running the following command line:

```
myuser@server:/var/www/html/folder/htdocs$ php remove.php
myuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Within remove.php I run:

`exec('sudo -u myuser /usr/bin/wipe '.$main_path.$base.' -f -c -s');`

And I've set my sudoers file:

`www-data ALL=(myuser) NOPASSWD: ALL`

And I've set sudoers to 0440:

`-r--r-----   1 root root        838 Sep 18 11:07 sudoers`

Why am I told that `myuser` isn't in the sudoers file when it is?

Comment: Are you *sure*? I don't think the system will lie to you about this.  Try `sudo adduser yourusername sudo`. You have to do this from a user that already has sudo privilege.

Comment: I have run that - gone back to my php script and am still getting the same message. I agree its bizarre that the system shouldn't lie! I'm either missing something obvious or have done something weird

Comment: which user executes the php script?

Comment: I'm now running it purely from the command line (outside of PHP) with `sudo -u myuser /usr/bin/wipe` and its erroring too - same error

Comment: `usermod -aG sudo myuser` and a reboot did the fix :) thanks

Comment: AFAIK `www-data ALL=(myuser) NOPASSWD: ALL` allows user `www-data` to execute `sudo -u myuser somecommand` - it does **not** allow `myuser` to execute `sudo` themself. See for example [Trying to understand the difference between “modernNeo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL” and “modernNeo ALL=(ALL) ALL” in the sudoers file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490838/65304)